# Query posts and custom post types within the same category

Tags: custom-post-types

i have a filter on my template which returns posts from a given category and displays them in a slider gallery. This is the code:

```
<?php
 if (is_page()) {
     $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
     $posts = get_posts( array('category' => 16) );
     if ($posts) {
         foreach ($posts as $post):
             setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

This works fine with "normal" posts. But I have created 3 custom post types (some of the entries tagged with the same category). And they don't show up. 
Could anyone please help how to customize this code in order to be able to use it also with CPT's? Thank you, Ralf

Comment: +1 for not using `query_posts`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need to do is specify the `'post_type'` argument which is only `'post'` by default.

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'category' => 16,
    'post_type' => array( 'post', '{another_post_type}', '{another_post_type}', '{another_post_type}' )
) );
```

You might also consider using `WP_Query` to make a custom loop instead. That's a bit personal preference but is probably the best practice for what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: Your first solution works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great. Make sure to accept the answer so others know!